# Perform function upon pressing enter after editing text in a ContentEditable element

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have a h1 element that I have set to ContentEditable = "true". Within that element, i wanted to restrict the text to one line only and after the first enter is pressed to set focus to another element of the page.

So i've set the css with nowrap and overflow hidden which visually restricts the css to one line. Now on pressing enter, i wanted to set the focus, so i started with the following basic jquery to detect pressing of enter,  but the alert doesnt work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.edit').keypress(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('You pressed enter!');
}
 });
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keydown` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCLgT/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.edit').keydown(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur().next().focus();
        return false;
      }
 });
 })
```

Comment: Sorry, I set both the element editable that might confused you. I changed code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dCLgT/1/. If you press enter on hr it will remove focus from hr.

Comment: Your jsfiddle example seems to  work, but in my app for some reason this isnt working. My js is a direct copy and paste of your code snippet.

Here's my html. Any ideas?

<h1 class="storytitle edit" id="storytitle" align="center"  contentEditable="true">

Comment: There might be some minor problem.have you copied code from jsfiddle as jsfiddle used to append extra characters at end of copy.

Comment: No, i copied it from here in StackOverflow

Comment: I've pasted it into jsFiddle and still not working. This is weird.
See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sxvX8/

Comment: There was problem with your code see http://jsfiddle.net/sxvX8/1/. you were missing { } for if. you have not selected jQuery from left side drop down .

Comment: My apologies, I missed that. It seems to be working fine in jsFiddle now, however when incorporating into my dust template i get unexpected token. Just out of curiosity, i don't suppose you know what could be causing that?

Comment: see if you have extra characters at the end of copied code. that could be problem.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be it. Oddly, if i paste the code into a different js file, then i get no errors, but the code never seems to execute.